# Laplace-like / cofactor expansion for Pfaffian

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, pfaffian

Wikipedia presents a recursive definition of the Pfaffian of a skew-symmetric matrix as $$ \operatorname{pf}(A)=\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq i}}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j+1+\theta(i-j)}a_{ij}\operatorname{pf}(A_{\hat{\imath}\hat{\jmath}}),$$ where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function. I have failed to find a proper reference for this result. Is it standard or does it require proper citation? What should one cite?

Comment: Maybe a particular case of Theorem 1 in http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aima.1995.1029 (no time to check, sorry). Should also be in Knuth's Overlapping Pfaffians paper.

Comment: For this kind of identities or more complicated ones Grassmann-Berezin integration is a powerful tool. See for example http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885803001465

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Yep, a prticular case of Theorem 1 of A Simple Proof of an Identity Concerning Pfaffians of Skew Symmetric Matrices by Dress, Wenzel. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Thanks. Could be useful some day.

Answer (score 5):

Your formula can be found in

*Fulton, William, Pragacz, Piotr*: [**Schubert varieties and degeneracy loci**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0096380), Lecture Notes in Mathematics **1689**, Springer. xi, 148 p. (1998). [ZBL0913.14016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0913.14016),

see in particular equation (D.1) p. 116.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you get the Pfaffian.  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$   Consider the symplectic $2$-form

$$ \omega = dx^1\wedge dx^2+\cdots +x^{2n-1}\wedge x^{2n} \in\Omega^2(\bR^{2n}). $$

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{n!}\omega^{\wedge n}:=\frac{1}{n!}\underbrace{\omega\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega}_n=dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{2n-1}\wedge dx^{2n} $$

Suppose that $A=(a_{ij})$ is a skew-symmetric  $2n\times 2n$ matrix. None that $\newcommand{\be}{\boldsymbol{e}}$

$$a_{ij}=(\be_i, A\be_j), $$

where $(\be_i)$ is the canonical basis  of $\bR^{2n}$.     Consider now the $2$-form

$$ \omega_A=-\sum_{i<j} aa_{ij}dx^i\wedge dx^j=\sum_{i<j} (A\be_i,\be_j) dx^i\wedge dx^j=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j} a_{ij} dx^i\wedge dx^j. $$

The top exterior power   of $\omega_A$ is a multiple $\mu$ of $\frac{1}{n!}\omega^{\wedge n}$

$$\omega_A^{\wedge n}=\frac{\mu}{n!} \omega^{\wedge n}. \tag{*}$$

The Pfaffian of $A$  is then   the multiple $\mu$.   If you write $\omega_A$ in the form

$$\omega_A =-\frac{1}{2}\sum_j a_{ij} dx^i\wedge dx^j-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k,\ell\neq i} a_{k\ell} dx^k\wedge dx^\ell  $$
  and use the equality (*) then you will get your formula.

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty much the approach used in the paper that was linked by Darij Grinberg in comments where it is used to prove more general identity.

Comment: This is  essentially  Berezin or fermionic integration.